# Excel VBA - Find and Update Table Values from Another Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I need to update some values in a table column from another sheet. For each row in the table called "tbPartnerList" find the row number in sheet ws2 where the value in ws2.Range("B:B") matches the value in column 1 of the table. Then transfer the associated value from ws2.Range("AH:AH") to the 14th column in the table. Although I can find the value in the ws2 I am struggling to return it to the table. Method not supported on [tbPartnerList].ListRows(row).Columns(14) = ws2.Cells(rng.row, 34)

```
Set ws2 = Sheet6

For Each row In [tbPartnerList].Rows
    partAccount = row.Columns(1).Value
    With ws2.Range("B:B")
        Set rng = .find(What:=partAccount, _
                                After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                MatchCase:=False)
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            [tbPartnerList].ListRows(row).Columns(14) = ws2.Cells(rng.row, 34)
        End If
    End With
Next
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `.Value` to the end of `Cells(rng.row,34)`? Also, is `Columns` a mehod of `.ListRows(row)` ? Finally, you have `.ListRows(row)` when it probably should be `.ListRows(row.row)`